How to interrupt an Azure Function running locally through Core Tools?
I have inherited a C# 6 Azure Function that I'm updating to C# 8.
We commonly run the function locally, either through VisualStudio or the Azure Core Tools (ie., func start). The function is fairly long-running, and re-starting a job can be non-trivial; thus, we had a system that would use Console.ReadLine() to initiate a safe shutdown.
The migration to C# 8 and/or from the in-process model to the isolated worker model has broken that system: neither Console.ReadLine() nor Console.ReadKey() appear to be hooked up to the terminal window - hitting "enter" doesn't do anything (ReadKey doesn't seem to respond to any keypress).
Specifically:
static async Task WaitForEnter()
{
    await Task.Delay(1);
    while (true)
    {
        var key = Console.ReadKey();
        if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
        {
            RequestExit("Manual exit request");
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
    RequestExit("Manual exit request");
}

with or without the while loop gets "stuck" on either ReadKey or ReadLine. I've verified that the function is entered via debug console writing and breakpoints, but the console is never read.
Ideally, I'd like the ReadLine option to work again: it's convenient and fairly established. Failing that, "best practice" would be appreciated.
In case it matters: I'm running on Windows 11; Core Tools Version 4.0.5907 (64-bit), Function Runtime Version: 4.834.3.22875.

I created .net6 Azure Function in-process model and migrated to .net 8 Isolated worker model.
I follow this Ms Doc to migrate the .net6 process model to .net8 Isolated worker model.

Change the  to .net8.0 in .csproj and add below packages.

<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.21.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.2.0" />


I also Added below line to .csproj

<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>


Add the new Item group to .csproj

<ItemGroup>
  <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext"/>
</ItemGroup>

Below is the complete .csproj file.
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <RootNamespace>My.Namespace</RootNamespace>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>


I added Program.cs file to the project.

Program.cs:
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services => {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .Build();
host.Run();


In local.settings.json set the "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated".
Below is Function.cs code for isolated worker model

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
namespace Function6
{
    public class HttpTriggerCSharp
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HttpTriggerCSharp> _logger;
        public HttpTriggerCSharp(ILogger<HttpTriggerCSharp> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
        [Function("HttpTriggerCSharp")]
        public IActionResult Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            return new OkObjectResult($"Welcome to Azure Functions, {req.Query["name"]}!");
        }
    }
}

Output:

To Interrupt an azure function running locally I used below code in program.cs:
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services => {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .Build();
var shutdownFilePath = "PathToShuntdown.txt";
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
Task.Run(() => MonitorShutdownFile(shutdownFilePath, cts.Token));
Console.CancelKeyPress += (sender, e) =>
{
    e.Cancel = true; 
    cts.Cancel(); 
};
await RunWithCancellation(host, cts.Token);
static async Task RunWithCancellation(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
{
    var functionHostTask = host.RunAsync(token);
    try
    {
        await functionHostTask;
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Host stopping due to cancellation.");
    }
}
static async Task MonitorShutdownFile(string path, CancellationToken token)
{
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Checking for shutdown file at: {path}");

        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Shutdown file detected. Exiting...");
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
        await Task.Delay(1000, token);
    }
}


This nearly works, but it seems that func still captures the ctrl+c and kills the dotnet process. Thus, the function terminates immediately rather than being able to gracefully respond to the request to exit.
